# Receive empty data set in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am so puzzled with this:

I have two identical set of code for retrieving data from database. One returns data and the other does not, even though data is expected.
The following is the one that returns empty set. There are sample data in the corresponding table.

This is the controller code:

```
namespace MVCPart1_5.Controllers
    {
        public class DepartmentController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Department
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                DepartmentContext oDepartmentContext = new DepartmentContext();
                List<Department> oDepartments = oDepartmentContext.Departments.ToList();

                return View(oDepartments);
            }
        }
    }
```

These are the models:

```
namespace MVCPart1_5.Models
{
    [Table("Department")]
    public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}


namespace MVCPart1_5.Models
{
    public class DepartmentContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { set; get; }
    }
}
```

and finally the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCPart1_5.Models.Department>
@using MVCPart1_5.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Department Set</h2>

<div style="font-family :Arial">
    <ul>
        @foreach (Department department in @Model)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink(department.Name, "Details", "Employee", new { departmentCode = department.Code })

            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

I also have the following in the global:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MVCPart1_5.Models.EmployeeContext>(null);
    Database.SetInitializer<MVCPart1_5.Models.DepartmentContext>(null);

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

}

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is oDepartments variable filled with data?

Comment: Try to put a break point at this line: `return View(oDepartments);`, then debug and check if `oDepartments` is empty or not.

Comment: The oDepartments returns a list with no item. I used the break point and that is the part that I found out the list count is 0 .

Comment: well it seems that you're using a wrong connection string if you're sure that exists data in your table.

Comment: there is a little tool named SQL Server Profiler which sometime could help

Comment: I get data from the same database for the employees with the same connection string. So I guess the connection string is correct.

Comment: Yes, I do have data in the Department table.

Comment: Sorry Your question is too broad, we doesn't have a cristal ball to see what doesn't work, trace your db call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your oDepartments variable is not filled with the data you should examine a connection string in your application because it's probably wrong (so it connects to another database).

Because your DbContext class is `DepartmentContext` and the default Entity Framework approach is to name connection string the same you should look for a connection string named `DepartmentContext`. Then try to connect to a database using credentials found in that connection string. I'm 99% sure you'll find empty Department table.

Remember that even if you connect with the same database server you could connect to wrong database.